# Git Add Without Directory?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

My git repo's master branch structure is as follows

```
/demo
    index.html
    style.css
    reset.css
jquery.dimlights.js
jquery.dimlights.css
jquery.dimlights.min.js
jquery.dimlights.min.css
readme.md
```

However in the gh-pages branch I just want the contents of `/demo` without the directory itself. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: As setting up `gh-pages` suggests to create an empty branch, why don't you just copy and insert the files? Seems like the easiest way. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just so I understand -- do you want the files contained in /demo to be at the top level of your repository?  If so, can't you just `git mv` them?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to include contents of a directory without the directory.  Where would the files live?  It does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
git rm (everything except demo)
git mv demo/* .
git commit -m "adding content to gh-pages"
```

Another way depending on how you want to handle the gh-pages branch is to create an orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
rm (everything except demo)
mv demo/* .
git add .
git commit -m "adding content to gh-pages"
```

Comment: This pretty much did it. In the end I actually just made a second local repo purely for the gh-pages branch. Thanks :)